# Brightness doesnt get saved when back button is pressed

Tags: android, save, back, brightness

I there, I have a seekbar on my application to change the brightness and its working.
Then problem is that, when I press the back button to navigate to another activity, the brightness goes back to default..

Here is my code to change brightness:

```
private void applyBrightnessListener() {
    SeekBar brightnessControl = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.brightnessControl);

    brightnessControl.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar arg0, int arg1, boolean arg2) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            float BackLightValue = (float)arg1/100;
            WindowManager.LayoutParams layoutParams = getWindow().getAttributes();
            layoutParams.screenBrightness = BackLightValue;
            getWindow().setAttributes(layoutParams);
            android.provider.Settings.System.putInt(
                GeneralSettings.this.getContentResolver(),
                android.provider.Settings.System.SCREEN_BRIGHTNESS,
                (int)BackLightValue);
        }

        @Override
        public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }

        @Override
        public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }
    });
}
```

Thanks alot in advance ;)

Comment: Looks like you are trying to change global device brightness level, are you checking if automatic mode is enabled or not?

Comment: Automatic mode is disabled

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sadly you need to track that brightness, and set it for each activity.  You can't set it once and have it stay.

So you would need to store the value in your preferences, or some other way, then when you start each activity, load the preference and set it in your activity.

One good way would be to subclass Activity, and put this code in the onCreate method.

```
                WindowManager.LayoutParams layoutParams = getWindow().getAttributes();
                layoutParams.screenBrightness = savedBackLightValue;
                getWindow().setAttributes(layoutParams);
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply! omg really? And everytime I make a new activity on my app I will need to extend that one ? :s

Comment: Yes.  It sounds like a pain, but if you subclass things, you only need to write it once (or a few times, if you have several types of Activities)

Comment: Yes I have like 10 activities, but okay I will test it, and if it works, at least is a solution :/  Better than nothing

Comment: I'm assuming you know this-- but if all your activities extend Activity, you can just make one new Activity class, maybe called BrightnessActivity that has the functionality in it and then have all your activities extend it instead of Activity (I'm never sure how familiar people are with Android)

Comment: Yes and that one, the BrightnessActivity extends the Activity itself, yes I am familiar with inheritance, its fine, and understood that. I was just looking for simpler solution. thanks! I will try it now, and if it works as supposed I will accept your answer ;)

Comment: This is not working, I am saving the brightness setting on another class, and on another activities at resume method I call the super.onResume() that is the BrightnessActivity, here I have that code you suggested, using the saved brightness .. but its goes back to default bright... thanks alot in advance!